# How to replace a sequence after a multiple of six characters?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, sirishortcuts

I want to replace a string, say “000000” to the letter L only if it comes after a multiple of six digits with regex. I am using Siri Shortcuts on iOS, and my project is a system managing binary strings. My current method is to split the base string into six-byte chunks, then to run my regex’s, but this is not as efficient as it can be and it crashes with larger strings.

For example:

```
Input: “000000010110100000000000”
Split for human reading: “000000-010110-100000-000000”
Desired output: “L010110100000L”
```

I’ve tried notations such as `(?=(\d{6})*)000000`, as well as replacing `*` with `+`, changing groups, writing `\d` six times instead of `\d{6}` and several other things, but I can’t figure out how to force it to a multiple of six. Usually, I get an output such as:

```
“L0101101L00000” instead of “L010110100000L”
```

Is there a way to ensure that there is a multiple of six digits (not characters) behind the string I want to replace? Alternatively, is there a way to put a character such as a space after every sixth character without removing the characters? Siri Shortcuts uses the ICU flavor of regex.

Comment: You wrote `I want to replace a string, say “000000” to the letter L only if it comes after a multiple of six digits`, but in the example, you expect the result `“L010110100000L”`. That is a contradiction, because the first set of `000000` does not come after anything. So the first `L` should NOT be there. Maybe you need to analyze and describe your problem better?

Comment: Here I consider 0 and multiple of 6. I’m using chunks of six bits in my code, so I just need to extract any matching chunk. My problem is that my system is ignoring chunk boundaries and I need a way to determine in the regex if the selected phrase is a chunk, thus the multiple of six. I’ll edit my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your first requirement correctly, you could use something like this:

```
(\G(?:\d{6})*?)(000000)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1L
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/K1gIcx/2).

---

For this part:

> Alternatively, is there a way to put a character such as a space after
>   every sixth character without removing the characters?

..you may use something like:

```
(\d{6})(?!$)
```

..and then replace it with `\$` followed by the character you want to add. For example `\$-`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WIdyx0/1).

Comment: In the demo, that works exactly how I want it to work. Unfortunately, in Shortcuts, neither \1 for replacing from a group nor \K to select the next character work. I don’t know if there’s a special way I have to escape \1, as the Replace block won’t parse it as a regex. I found a guide to regex in Shortcuts, so I’ll comment if I find any alternatives to these. Thank you, even though this hasn’t quite worked I’m closer to what will work.

Comment: Aha! Instead of \(group) to select a group, Shortcuts uses $(group). It is now working!

Comment: @TACoder Yeah my bad! Edited the answer and also fixed another issue with the second solution to prevent appending a separator character at the end of the string.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with other strings. If I put in 1101101... for example, and search for 101101, it will still select the 101101 even though it isn’t on a multiple of six. I can’t figure out how to add a section to make sure there are no occurrences like that, and there could be an easier way. This regex seems to match six characters at a time until it finds the phrase to replace, but if it cannot find it there, it will still replace it when it gets there.

Comment: The regex that fixes this problem is '''(\G(?:\d{6})*?)(101101)'''. Now it will only match from the beginning or last match, ensuring that there are always a multiple of six digits from the beginning.

Comment: @TACoder You're right. `\G` will fix this issue. I thought your regex flavor didn't support `\G` or `\K`?

Comment: Actually, [\A|\G]. I can’t edit that comment now. The flavor is ICU, which supports \G, but not \K.

Comment: It’s almost perfect now. It is still getting stuck on characters that aren’t digits, and I don’t believe ICU has a symbol to ignore characters. I’m trying to put in something to just pass over the letters. Thank you again for your help on this!

Comment: @TACoder Please provide sample input and the expected output. Maybe I can help you.

Comment: After some processing, I get a string such as S110100... and when the regex for 110100 passes over the string, it doesn’t replace 110100 because of the S. Let’s say it should replace 110100 with L, so the expected output would be SL... (ellipses just indicating more characters, not actually part of the string). I can’t find a way to ignore the characters with ICU, so I’m trying to implement [a-zA-Z]*? where it seems to need it so it can pass over those characters.

Comment: Here is what I have now: (\G[A-z\+/]?(?:\d{6}[A-z\+/]?)*?)(101101). This seems to work. I’m going to test for a bit and run some speed comparisons vs using the regex to separate every chunk of six characters and then running a replace for just the string I want to replace.